# mutt: gmail IMAP unresponsive

Tags: mutt, imap

I read gmail via IMAP with the `mutt` MUA. If I leave `mutt` open and idle for several minutes, then the program becomes unresponsive to keyboard input, requiring me to kill the process. I am not certain whether the issue is IMAP timeout or something else. I have changed pertinent IMAP settings to values that should preclude IMAP timeout. Relevant settings from my `.muttrc` configuration file:

```
unset imap_passive
set imap_keepalive = 120
set timeout = 30
set mail_check = 60
```

How can I troubleshoot the keyboard unresponsiveness especially with regard to determining whether it is attributable to loss of the IMAP connection. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check your logs for anything interesting, e.g. `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/mail.log`.

You could also open up a separate SSH session or console and attach an `strace` to the mutt process once you've started it.  Locate the pid with `ps aux | grep mutt` in your other session/console, and do

`strace -p pid`

You should be able to get an idea of what mutt is hanging/crashing on, or at least a new trail to follow for troubleshooting.  You may also want add the `-f` switch to strace to follow the child processes if it forks.  Let me know what you find...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The `messages` log is filled with the message `Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain` every ~3 minutes, which is unexpected because I thought I had disabled wireless (it must have turned itself back on after a reboot). I suppose this could relate to an IMAP timeout, although I had a simultaneous active Ethernet connection throughout. All the `mail.*` logs are empty. Thanks for suggesting `strace`, as I wasn't aware of this tool. I will let you know if there are any interesting system call errors. Thanks again.

Comment: PS: Is it a bad idea to leave `mutt` running on my computer and then later `ssh` into my computer from another terminal and launch another instance of `mutt` for temporary use?

Comment: @user001 If you run mutt inside a screen or tmux process, you can just attach to the running process.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the network going down and up, particularly wireless. Mutt uses blocking IO which is an old design and is not likely to be fix anytime soon. See: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=105030.

The issue is likely to be resolved by offlineimap + mutt setup.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely related to [bug 2540](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/ticket/2540) in which Mutt crashes after an IMAP timeout.

There are [several other IMAP related crash tickets](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/query?status=closed&group=resolution&milestone=1.6) that have been closed for the 1.6 release. Hopefully it will be released soon as I am facing the same issue.