# Why does mutt keep asking for imap username and password?

Tags: mutt, imap

Unsetting mutt's configuration variables `imap_user`, `imap_pass` (and perhaps `preconnect`, `imap_authenticators` as well) via an [`account-hook . "unset ... "`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#account-hook) call, seems to be common practice, if not a necessity, for handling multiple imap accounts (see [Managing multiple IMAP/POP accounts (OPTIONAL)](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#ss4.12), [Mutt imap multiple account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86583/13011), [mutt: gmail IMAP unresponsive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44405/13011), [an account-hook related configuration file in funtoo.org](http://www.funtoo.org/Mutt#account_hooks)).

Currently I handle only one account via IMAP. Plans for multiple account handling lead me to follow the instructions found in the last of the above mentioned links ([someone's example of mutt configuration](http://www.funtoo.org/Mutt#golodhrim.27s_mutt_config)). Therefore, in a similar way, I used the following:

```
account-hook . 'unset imap_user; unset imap_pass; unset tunnel'
account-hook 'imaps://mail.domain.net:993/INBOX/' "set imap_user=UserName@domain.net"
account-hook 'imaps://mail.domain.net:993/INBOX/' "set imap_pass=${my_password}"
```

This is stored in a separate file (named `account_hooks`) and sourced from inside `muttrc`. For reasons I don't understand, mutt keeps asking for the *username* and the *password*. However, if the variables `imap_user` and `imap_pass` are set directly in `muttrc`, e.g.

```
set my_password="`gpg --decrypt ~/.mutt/password.gpg`"
set imap_authenticators='login'
set imap_login = 'UserName@domain.net'
set imap_user = 'UserName@domain.net'
set imap_pass ="${my_password}"
```

everything works fine. The `account_hooks` file is the first one sourced and no other `account-hook . "unset ..."` call(s) exist(s) anywhere else.

**Update**,  The `folder-hooks` file is (and was, I think) as follows:

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Folders and hooks
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# folder-hook 'imaps://UserName%domain.net@mail.domain.net:993/'
set folder = "~/.maildir"       # IMAP: local, using offlineimap -- folder="imaps://mail.domain.net:993/INBOX/"
source ~/.mutt/mailboxes        # source automatically generated mailboxes
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"        # spoolfile='imaps://mail.domain.net:993/'
set postponed = "+INBOX/Drafts"

# Sending -----------------------------------------------------------------
set smtp_url="smtp://UserName@domain.net@mail.domain.net:587/"
set smtp_pass=${my_password}
set record = "+INBOX/Sent"
set copy=yes

# Index format ----------------------------------------------------------------
folder-hook *[sS]ent* 'set sort=threads'
folder-hook *[sS]ent* 'set sort_browser=reverse-date'
folder-hook *[sS]ent* 'set sort_aux=reverse-last-date-received'
folder-hook *[sS]ent* 'set index_format="%2C | %Z [%d] %-30.30t (%-4.4c) %s"'
folder-hook ! *[sS]ent* 'set index_format="%2C | %Z [%d] %-30.30F (%-4.4c) %s"':
```

**Why does, the separate file *account_hooks*, not feed properly the variables of interest in this case (i.e. *imap_user* and *imap_pass*)?**

Comment: If you're still interested in answer I would like to see the `folder-hook` lines you have in your `.muttrc`. Then I can draw some conclusions and offer a complete solution.

Comment: @brauner, so late and busy, apologies. I haven't found the time to experiment more with this, since I didn't need it. I have to trace back the `folder-hook` settings I used at the time, I guess I have'm as a backup.

Comment: can you post a debug file from 'mutt -d 5' ?

Comment: @asdmin for the moment, the response is `DEBUG was not defined during compilation.  Ignored.`. Once I'll find some time, I'll recompile and post back.

Comment: @kyrias thnx for edits

Comment: It happens to me when `imap_user` var is not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set username and password directly, but it doesn't work when you use an `account-hook`, so probably the `account-hook` doesn't work.

An `account-hook` consists of a *regexp* for the mailboxes, and those commands which should be executed if a mailbox matches the *regexp*.

Since the commands (`set imap_user`, `set imap_pass`) are not executed, we can assume that the `regexp` didn't match your mailboxes.

You are using 'imaps://mail.domain.net:993/INBOX/' which is very specific. Probably your mailboxes are named slightly different.

Is this the only mail account from `mail.domain.net` you are using?
If so, reducing the *regexp* to `'mail.domain.net'` should be enough to match your mailboxes.

```
account-hook . 'unset imap_user; unset imap_pass; unset tunnel
account-hook mail.domain.net "set imap_user=UserName@domain.net"
account-hook mail.domain.net "set imap_pass=${my_password}"
```

Comment: I came back to work this out. Most likely your interpretation is right. I'll, hopefully, verify this soon. Thank you.

Comment: If both `set imap_user` and `set imap_pass` are not executed, why am I asked for a password for `Password for UserName@mail.domain.net:` then? Exactly the user-id and domain set for `account-hook` in the `account-hooks` file?

Comment: I got it fixed! I think I was missing to provide the `${my_password}` correctly for the `smtp_pass` variable. It was `${password}`... :-/

Comment: Regarding my last comment, after multiple experimental edits, it seems that I wrongly used `"${password}"`, instead of `"${my_password}"`. The `account-hooks` file seems to work for at least 2 acounts, now, properly.  And another third one for which it get's stuck to another issue, namely an `SSL failed: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol`. But that is not directly related to the Question aksed and answered here. So, excluding "typos", the problem, initially, was indeed the `regexp` not matching the mailbox(es) in question.